# What is the purpose of debug/release configurations in Visual Studio 2008/2010 compiling to different folders?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration

What is the point of compiling assemblies to separate folders?  At my work we have 50+ projects which live across a few different solutions.  When projects are in the same solution you can set a Project Reference and it picks up the assembly in the \debug or \release folder accordingly.  But when setting an external reference (via Browse) and you point explicitly to \debug\assebmly.dll or \release\assembly.dll the referencing project will not pick up a "release" assembly if the referenced project is compiled in release mode.

I understand that normally a build process can handle this, but in the case where I need to compile a project in release mode outside of a build process this means I have to check all external references to make sure they are pointing to the \release folders.  This is something easy to miss - and I do not want to have to think about everytime.  So my thoughts are to always compile the assembly for a project to the \bin folder whether debug or release configuration is selected.  Any cons to this approach?

[I also have a blog post on this topic here.](http://metabytes.net/2010/10/14/visual-studio-solution-configurations-and-assembly-references/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is simple, because *not* using separate folders is so much worse.  You'll build Release, find out something is amiss, switch back to Debug and *not* get the actual Debug versions of the assemblies.  Unless you explicitly use Build + Clean first.  Now you'll go sword-fighting or visiting SO, forgetting why you switched back.

Dealing with project output from another solution is straight forward too: *always* add a reference to the Release version.  Because if you needed to debug and alter that assembly then you would have added the project to your current solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's not only the binaries, it's the intermediate files as well. That's why it's necessary to compile to different directories.

If you want to have your binaries in a bin folder, then change the output file or add a `copy` as a custom build step. I understand that this adds some inconvenience to your workflow, but you have to realize that building to the same folders by default would be a huge PITA for a lot of people.

Also, when adding references to projects outside of your solution, try to use macros like `$(ConfigurationName)` in your reference to automagicaly insert "Release" or "Debug" in your path as necessary. (I envy you for only having to deal with the two default configurations...)

And then, here is another idea: Projects can live in more then one solution. Have a solution for each valid combination of projects that you have to build. This way you will allays use the Project Dependency feature and will always build up-to-date builds of your solution with one click.

Comment: what are "the intermediate files"?

Comment: but the files in the obj folder are at the root project folder level whereas the debug and release folders are inside the bin folder...  so I'm not sure I understand what you mean by saying that the intermediate files are affected as well.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Well, not for my projects. As Hans wrote, if you would build different configurations into the same folders, you would need to clean & rebuild each of them from scratch. If you have projects that have more configurations then Debug and Release, and other projects depend on different configurations, then it would be impossible to build the whole solution without using separate folders.

Comment: I understand that, my point is that the default configurations of debug and release, while compiling the assemblies and vshost files to the separate \bin\debug\ and bin\release\ folders, the obj folder lives at the root of the project folder and thus seems to be shared between the two default configurations.

Comment: They should be built to separate folders by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you build everything in to a single folder, switch configurations, and then do a partial solution build (say, just of your data component), you can easily end up with a mixture of debug and release assemblies being used.  That's a Bad Thing.

By keeping the builds in separate folders, you can ensure that all assemblies are built from the same configuration.